# Django PointField with geography=True can't save data: SQL function error

Tags: django, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have a `Django 3.1.2` with GIS extension installed, `PostgreSQL 12` and `PostGIS 3`.

In my model I'm trying to use a `PointField` with `geography=True` to store real-world coordinates:

```
location = models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_("Lat/Lon coordinates"))
```

In the admin menu I'm using the OSMWidget to enter coordinates:

```
location = forms.PointField(widget=forms.OSMWidget(attrs={'map_width': 800, 'map_height': 500, 'default_zoom': 15}))
```

When this is saved Django runs into the following SQL error:

```
INSERT INTO "challenges_point" ("track_id", "sortkey", "name", "location") VALUES (15, 10, 'Start', ST_Transform(ST_GeogFromWKB('\x...'::bytea), 4326)) RETURNING "challenges_point"."id";
ERROR:  function st_transform(geography, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "location") VALUES (15, 10, 'Start', ST_Transfo...
                                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

`ST_Transform()` is used to transform geometry points (which is used as data type if `geography=False` is used for the `PointField`). But I'm not sure what's required to make it work with geography.

Comment: Can you try adding srid=4326 to your form field?

Comment: You mean: "forms.OSMWidget(attrs={'srid': 4326, 'map_width': 800 ..."? I added that, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you override the PointField it has no srid set and ST_Transform is used to convert the geom to the right spatial reference.

There's several ways to correctly change the widget, but I'll give you the simplest one with your current code:

```py
location = forms.PointField(
    srid=4326,
    widget=forms.OSMWidget(
        attrs={'map_width': 800, 'map_height': 500, 'default_zoom': 15}
    )
)
```

The other ways are:

- Extend [`Model.formfield()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.formfield) and change `form_class.widget` to OSMWidget.
- Implement [`ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) and only specify the widget attribute. This works because you do not have to override the entire field, but just specific attributes, the defaults will come from `Model.formfield()` above, which correctly sets the srid.
- Override just the widget using the [ModelForm's meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields). Works in a similar way as the previous.